# Aligning button's text to the left

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the next code:

```
<button onClick={this.openModal}>[{this.props.defaultValue}]</button>
```

The text obtained from

```
[{this.props.defaultValue}]
```

is always centered. Is there a way to make it be aligned to the left?

This is what I am trying at present:

```
const bstyle = { 
        textAlign:'left',
        color: 'white'
     };
    const {open} = this.state;
    return (
            <div>
            <button style={bstyle} onClick={this.onOpenModal}>[{this.props.defaultValue}]</button>

 ....
```

with no results. :-(
I can see the button aligned to the left. But its text to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style expects an `object`.

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a
>   string.

Set the `padding-left` to `0px`;

write it like this:

```
<button onClick={this.openModal} style={{paddingLeft:'0px'}}>{this.props.defaultValue}</button>
```

Check this:

```js
var App = () => {
   return (
      <div>
         <button style={{paddingLeft:'0px'}}>Hello World</button>
      </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set 'text-align' for this

```
<button onClick={this.openModal} style="text-align: left;">[{this.props.defaultValue}]</button>
```

**or you can define a `class` and set it's CSS**

```
<button onClick={this.openModal} class="text-left">[{this.props.defaultValue}]</button>

<style>
    .text-left{
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: From the first one I got:
Uncaught Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: the you can use `style={{paddingLeft:'0px'}}` or `style={{textAlign:'left'}}` or both